# AndroidPay unrecoverable error in onActivityResult

Tags: android, stripe-payments, payment, onactivityresult, android-pay

I'm trying to use the AndroidPay API. I set the environment to WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX
but when I click the Pay button in the onActivityResult my errorCode is 8, and it returns the resultCode 1.

Someone know's why that error is being returned?
Also since I'm not from the US I found an APK on the net and successfully installed it on my device and added a card. So this works on that part.

Answer (score 1):

Would you try to set environment to WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST?
WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX is test environment for Google Wallet before Google Wallet be replaced by Android Pay.

Comment: Yeah later I replaced the ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX with ENVIRONMENT_TEST. Now I get the "TEST_GATEWAY_TOKEN" String as a result.
Everywere I asked people told me to use ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX but it looks like they fixed that now, so ENVIRONMENT_TEST is the right way to do it. Now I just have to send the APK to Google for review and they will open the PRODUCTION environment if everything is fine.

Comment: Yeah thanks. The problem is that this is nowhere explained. It has just a little description in the Stripe AndroidPay documentation.